# csvで読み込んだリストに情報を加えたいがNoneが返ってくる

Tags: python, python3, csv

csvで読み込んだ行に情報(synonym='great')を追加して新しいファイルを作ろうと試みました。

```
import csv

synonym = 'great'

def csv_start():
    with open("svl1.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        with open("new_svl1.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as new_file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
            for line in csv_reader:

                # mkrowがNone
                mkrow = line.append('synonym')
                csv_writer.writerow(mkrow)
csv_start()
```

以上を実行したらエラーが返ってきて、mkrowがNoneだそうです。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "func.py", line 24, in
<module>
    csv_start()   File "func.py", line 22, in csv_start
    csv_writer.writerow(mkrow)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType
```

試しにlineだけプリントしてみたらしっかりcsvから読み込んだリストが返ってきます。どうしたら、リストに値を追加できるのでしょうか？

Comment: sapcal000 さんがやりたい事というのは「CSV データ(svl1.csv)に synonym というカラムを追加して "great" という値(文字列)を入れる」という事でしょうか？ そうでしたら pandas を使うと良いかもしれません。`pd.read_csv('svl1.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig').assign(synonym = 'great').to_csv('new_svl1.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Comment: このsynonymは, svl1.csvの一行目が英単語になっていて、それをスクレイピングでオンライン辞書から類義語をとってきて、新しいファイルにsvl1の情報(意味や発音記号など)に取ってきた類義語をつけ足して書き込もうとしてました。そのためにsynonymにとりあえずgreatをいれておきした。pandasの方法を教えてくれてありがとうございます。試してみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リスト操作(`append`等)の戻り値は処理結果のオブジェクトを返していません。

[5. データ構造](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html)

> `insert`,`remove`,`sort`などのリストを操作するメソッドの戻り値が表示されていないことに気が付いたかもしれません。これらのメソッドは`None`を返しています。[1] これは Python の変更可能なデータ構造全てについての設計上の原則となっています。

この場合は`line`そのものが書き換えられていますので、それを使えば良いでしょう。

ただし「csvで読み込んだ行に情報(synonym='great')を追加して」という意図と、`line.append('synonym')`という処理が合っているようには見えないのですが。

Comment: 読み込んだ行に追加するのでなくて、読み込んだ値に新たな値を加えて新しいファイルに書き込む。でした。（この日本語であってますか？）

Comment: 処理結果を返さないからNoneだったんですね。これから気を付けたいと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 全体的な処理内容については、metropolisさんのコメントを参考に、必要ならば新たな質問を起こしてみてください。