# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable エラーの対処法

Tags: python, python3

[AOJ ITP1_9_B](https://onlinejudge.u-aizu.ac.jp/courses/lesson/2/ITP1/9/ITP1_9_B)に関してのコードで、
slicingを使って文字列先頭の数文字を最後尾に移動させたいのですが、

```
word = list(input())
time = int(input())
for k in range(time):
  h = int(input())
  tmp1 = word[h:]
  tmp2 = tmp1.extend(word[:h])
  word = tmp2
print(word)
```

この場合、

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-42a708007e58> in <module>()
      3 for k in range(time):
      4   h = int(input())
----> 5   tmp1 = word[h:]
      6   tmp2 = tmp1.extend(word[:h])
      7   word = tmp2

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

とエラーが出てしまいます。
Noneのタイプのobjectは何を指しているのでしょうか。

```
print(type(word))
```

としてもきちんと

```
<class 'list'>
```

と帰ってきます。
原因が不明なので、どなたか教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 追記です。```tmp1```はきちんとlist型になっているのですが、tmp2が急にNoneType型になってしまっています。その原因が分かりません。

Comment: 追記は「編集」から自由におこなえますので、そちらからお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考までに、slicing は文字列に対しても使用できます。ですので、`word = input()` で読み込んで、`word = word[h:] + word[:h]` とすることも可能です。

Comment: ちなみにタイトル「...エラーの対処法」と記事詳細「...何を指しているのでしょうか。...原因不明なので、...教えていただけると...」が微妙にずれている(バラけている)感じです。質問には全体的な統一感がある方が望ましいでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の記事と同件ですね。
[csvで読み込んだリストに情報を加えたいがNoneが返ってくる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62319/26370)

リスト操作(`extend`を含む)の戻り値は処理結果のオブジェクトではなく`None`を返します。
質問のソースの以下の処理は、`tmp2`と`word`に`None`を代入することになります。

```
tmp2 = tmp1.extend(word[:h])
word = tmp2
```

以下の処理は、ループの初回では`word`は有効なリストですが、ループの2回目は`None`なのでエラーになります。

```
tmp1 = word[h:]
```

それからsliceして付け替える処理とか順番も微妙に間違っている感じですね。
いったん切り出して連結するなら、おそらく以下のようになると思われます。
(と書いたら@metropolisさんがもっと効率的な処理をコメントされていましたが)

```
tmp1 = word[:h]
word = word[h:]
word.extend(tmp1)
```